# jquery selector function failing on ajax reponse html data

Tags: jquery, ajax, string, parsing

In my jquery code, I am using an ajax get function to get the html code of a page. I want to then get a certain element from it, but when I try to do that, jquery gives this error:

```
SCRIPT5022: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
```

on the html string.

```
$.ajax({
    url: myURL,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function (data) {
        g = $('#MainLeftCell', $(data)).html(); // ERROR occurs here
        alert(g);
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("An error occured when searching.");
    }
});
```

I think it because there might be some weird sequence of code in the html string that the jquery parser cannot recognize. The page its getting it from is a SharePoint page.

Is there someway to fix this?

Comment: what does alert(data) give you ?

Comment: Tough to say anything without seeing the contents of `data`. Is it possible to share at least a chunk of that?

Comment: I tried alert(data), that works, and I can see the whole code.

Comment: Is it possible you have a timing issue? I've had situations in which the data passed to success() wasn't the true successful data. Try an async:false and see if your result is any different, it may give you a clue. The jquery selector looks good.

Comment: Can you modify the code, I don't know how to write that.

Comment: @Half_Duplex no, that's not possible, and async: false won't help it.

Comment: yeah, I just tried it, and I still get the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely your HTML isn't valid for usage with the `$()` method. Pass it to `$.parseHTML` first.

```
var g = $('#MainLeftCell', $.parseHTML(data)).html();
```

If that gets rid of the error but still doesn't work, most likely `#MainLeftCell` is a top level element and you'll have to use .filter to get it.

```
var g = $($.parseHTML(data)).filter('#MainLeftCell').html();
```

A more general solution is

```
var g = $("<div>").html(data).find("#MainLeftCell").html();
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a syntax error there...why don't you use `find()`..its cleaner

```
g = $(data).find('#MainLeftCell').html();
```

Comment: The error is probably happening here: `$(data)` due to either **invalid html**, or html that **doesn't start with `<`**

Comment: @omega if it doesn't start with `<`, you can't pass it to `$()`.